# $QR$ decomposition of a matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone please help me in showing that the Matrix $R$ in the $QR$ decomposition of a martix $A$ is invertible by showing its diagonal entries are non zero?

Comment: Could you give a little bit more context? What have you tried so far? In any case, as written, this isn't true. As you can decompose *any* matrix $A$ into an *orthogonal* (or *unitary*) $Q$ and a triangular matrix $R$. However if the matrix $A$ you are starting with is not invertible then so $R$ cannot be.

Comment: Basically i have tried showing that the diagonal entries in R are non zero by showing that the inner product of each entry is not orthogonal if this makes any sense

Comment: In any case the matrix A must have Linearly Independant columns

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, in general this is not true.

Any matrix $A \in$ M(m x n, $\mathbb{R}$) has a QR-decomposition $A = QR$ with $Q \in O(m)$ and $R = \begin{bmatrix}
   R_1\\
   0
\end{bmatrix} \in $ M(m x n, $\mathbb{R}$), where $R_1 \in$ M(n x n, $\mathbb{R}$) is an upper triangular matrix.

So your question (asking if $R$ is invertible) only makes sense if $A$ is a square matrix – then $R = R_1$. 
Then you get (because $Q$ is orthogonal matrix):

$$ \det(A) = \det(QR) = \det(Q) \cdot \det(R) = \pm \det(R)$$

So $$\det(A) \neq 0 \iff \det(R) \neq 0$$ Thus $A$ is invertible iff $R$ is invertible. As $R$ is an upper triangular matrix, this is equivalent to that $R$'s diagonal entries are non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

The $QR$ decomposition is attained by doing Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization; if $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ are the columns of $A$ (assumed to be linearly independent), one builds step by step vectors $u_1,\dots,u_n$ such that
$u_{k+1}$ is the difference between $v_{k+1}$ and its orthogonal projection on the subspace spanned by $u_1,\dots,u_k$. Thus we have, for some coefficients $\alpha_{1,k+1},\dots,\alpha_{k,k+1}$,
$$
u_{k+1}=v_{k+1}-\alpha_{1,k+1}u_1-\dots-\alpha_{k,k+1}
$$
Consider the $n\times n$ matrix
$$
R_0=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \alpha_{1,2} & \alpha_{1,3} & \dots & \alpha_{1,n} \\
0 & 1 & \alpha_{2,3} & \dots & \alpha_{2,n} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \dots & \alpha_{3,n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & \dots & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The matrix $R_0$ is upper unitriangular, so it is invertible; if
$$
Q_0=\begin{bmatrix}u_1 & u_2 & \dots & u_n\end{bmatrix}
$$
then, by definition,
$$
Q_0R_0=\begin{bmatrix}v_1 & v_2 & \dots & v_n\end{bmatrix}=A
$$
Now consider the diagonal matrix
$$
D=\begin{bmatrix}
\|u_1\| & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & \|u_2\| & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & \|u_n\|
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and set
$$
Q=Q_0D^{-1},\qquad R=DR_0
$$
This is the required decomposition, because obviously
$$
Q^TQ=(D^{-1})^TQ_0^TQ_0D^{-1}=I_n
$$
because by construction $Q_0^TQ_0=I_n$.

The matrix $R$ is invertible, because $D$ and $R_0$ are invertible.

Comment: Sir, In book by Howard Anton The matrix $R$ is given by $\begin{pmatrix} <u_1, q_1> & <u_2, q_1> & . & . & . & <u_n, q_1> \\ 0 & <u_2, q_2> & . & . & .   & <u_n, q_2> \\ .....\\.....\\ 0 & 0 & . & . & . & <u_n, q_n,>\end{pmatrx}$ where  $u_1, ..., u_n$ are linearly independent column vectors of $A$ and $q_1,....,q_n$ are orthonormal column vectors of $Q$. So to show this matrix $R$ is invertible we must show that diagonal entries are nonzero. But how?