# QR decompositon for singular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, orthogonality, orthonormal

I read in textbook that **every $m$ by $n$ matrix with independent columns can be factored into $A=QR$. The columns of $Q$ are orthonormal, and $R$ is upper triangular and invertible.**

I don't fully understand why $R$ is invertible when $A$ has independent columns. My thought is:

$A=QR\rightarrow Q^TA=R$ (multiply both sides by $Q^T$, and $Q^TQ=I$)

If $A$ is not square but has right inverse $A^{-1}$, then

$Q^TAA^{-1}Q=I=RA^{-1}Q$

So $A^{-1}Q$ is the inverse of $R$. But having right inverse requires independent rows, and I don't see how independent columns are related to it.

To clear my doubt, I looked at some other materials, and saw the following statement:

**Every invertible matrix has a $QR$ decomposition, where $R$ is invertible.**
As  a  side  note,  it  bears  mentioning  that  this  result  holds  even  if  the  matrix  is  not invertible: **Every matrix has a $QR$ decomposition, though $R$ may not always be invertible.**

It confused me even more. If a matrix $A$ does not have independent columns, how will its $QR$ decomposition be like? As far as I know, $Q$ has pairwise orthogonal columns, all of unit length, and its shape is the same as $A$. But if $A$ doesn't have independent columns in the first place, how do we find the corresponding $Q$?

I am stuck and hope someone can help me make it clear. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: To say a matrix is invertible is to suggest that it is a square matrix.  Otherwise, I would say that it has a left/right inverse.  

I would split this question into two separate questions.  

Please also include the exact wording from the textbook.  Your statements from the textbook feel paraphrased, which can lead to confusion.  People are more likely to answer a question (especially if it requires some work) when they are confident that the claim being interrogated has been stated precisely.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've included the original words from the textbook. Hope this makes my problem clearer.

Comment: Reading johnnycrab's answer at the following link, I'm left with the impression that the textbook has poor wording, and it is sending you on a wild goose chase.  Wikipedia mentions nothing about invertibility in the rectangular case, so I think it's best to assume that invertibility is restricted to the square case (as I always would have before reading your question).

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675714/qr-decomposition-of-a-matrix-a

Comment: @GingerBreadMan As I state in my answer below your comment, there are two common types of $QR$-decomposition.  Wikipedia focuses on the type where $R$ has the same size as $A$, but in the skinny $QR$-decomposition $R$ is square and talking about invertibility makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Regarding your original question:

We want to show that if $A$ has linearly independent columns and $A = QR$ with $R$ square and upper triangular (in fact I'll ignore the properties of $Q$), then $R$ must be invertible.

Note that $A$ has linearly independent columns if and only if $Ax = 0$ implies that $x = 0$ for $x \in \Bbb R^n$.

Now, suppose for the purpose of contradiction that $R$ fails to be invertible.  It follows that the columns of $R$ fail to be linearly independent, which is to say that $Rx = 0$ has a non-zero solution.  This contradicts our statement about $A$, however, since the same non-zero $x$ satisfies
$$
Ax = (QR)x = Q(Rx) = Q(0) = 0.
$$

---

### Regarding the different kinds of $QR$-decompositions:

The confusion here stems from the fact that there are different versions of the $QR$ decomposition.  Your "other materials" state the following:

> Every invertible matrix has a $QR$ decomposition, where $R$ is invertible...  Every matrix has a $QR$ decomposition, though $R$ may not always be invertible.

In this context, a "$QR$ decomposition" requires an orthogonal matrix $Q$ (so $Q$ is always square) and an upper-triangular matrix $R$ of the same size as $A$.

With this definition, $R$ will have the same rank as $A$ since we have $R = Q^TA$, and $Q^T$ is an invertible matrix.

On the other hand, your original source states the following:

> Every $m$ by $n$ matrix with independent columns can be factored into $A=QR$. The columns of $Q$ are orthonormal, and $R$ is upper triangular and invertible.

In this context, $Q$ is not necessarily square, but $R$ is.  Since both $Q$ and $R$ are smaller matrices, this is sometimes called a "thin" or "reduced" factorization.  Since you are looking at a statement about matrices $A$ with linearly independent columns, let's focus on this case.

First, note that since the columns are linearly independent, we necessarily have $m \geq n$.  In the case where $m > n$, we can break write the product as follows:
$$
A = QR = \pmatrix{Q_1 & Q_2} \pmatrix{\tilde R\\0}
$$
The sizes here are as follows. $Q_1: m\times n$, $Q_2: m \times (m-n)$, $R: n \times n$, $0: (m-n) \times n$.

In fact, this partition is confromable for a block-matrix product.  With block-matrix multiplication, we find that
$$
QR = \pmatrix{Q_1 & Q_2} \pmatrix{\tilde R\\0} = Q_1\tilde R + Q_20 = Q_1 \tilde R.
$$
So, $A = Q_1 \tilde R$ is a "thin" $QR$-decomposition where the columns of $Q_1$ are orthonormal (but $Q_1$ is not necessarily square) and if $A$ has linearly independent columns, then $\tilde R$ is invertible.